# jquery contains is throwing an error when I search paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to search different elements for the TM and Registers symbols ® & ™. I tried writing a very general identifier like *:contains('™').each(); however this wasn't finding the correct elements. So I got more specific, believing it would only be in the headings and wrote *:headers:contains('™').each();. It looks like it is also appearing in some paragraphs.
I didn't want to rewrite the code so I just added an argument to it's call. So my call went from

```
   addText(){
           $('*:header:contains("™")').each(function(){
                var str = $(this).html();
                var position = str.indexOf('™');

            //0, position is the string preceding the superscripted string
            //position is the superscripted string
            //position+1 is the string after the superscripted string
            var output= str.substr(0, position)+'<sup>™</sup>'+str.substr(position+1);
            $(this).html(output);
        });
    }
    } 
}
```

to

```
 addText('element'){
{$('*:'+element+':contains("™")').each(function(){
            var str = $(this).html();
            var position = str.indexOf('™');

            //0, position is the string preceding the superscripted string
            //position is the superscripted string
            //position+1 is the string after the superscripted string
            var output= str.substr(0, position)+'<sup>™</sup>'+str.substr(position+1);
            $(this).html(output);
        });
    }
    }
}
```

When I run the code with 'header' as the argument, that is `addText('header');` it works fine. However when I run the code as `addText('p');` I get

```
jquery.min.js?v=2.2.3:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: p
```

Comment: `:header` is a jQuery extension, e.g., all h1, h2, etc. https://api.jquery.com/header-selector/. `:p` isn't.

Comment: `p` is not a pseudo selector. I think you want to use `$('p').each(...)` instead.

Comment: Thank you I completely glossed over the ':' in front of the p. If one of you wants to answer the question I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: Try for the trademark symbol instead using &#8482 or \u2122